# Как должно правильно звучать предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

В сентябрьском номере журнала "Уюта" можно прочитать ряд статей о том, как дом сделать теплее, а проживание в нем - экономичнее.

Answer (score 5):

В сентябрьском номере журнала «Уют» можно прочитать ряд статей о том, как  сделать дом теплее, а проживание в нём — экономичнее.

При наличии родового слова "журнал" название не склоняется.

Comment: _Vera: При наличии **приложения** "журнал" название не склоняется._ === В словосочетании _**журнал "Уют"**_ приложением является не слово _**журнал**_, а название этого журнала -- _**"Уют"**_. Лучше написать примерно так:  _При наличии **родового слова**…_

Comment: Вера, я надеялся, что прислушаетесь к моему совету, но... Ваш ответ исправлять не решаюсь, попробую сам дать более правильный (с моей точки зрения) ответ.

Comment: Классическое понятие приложения как определения, выраженного существительным, не слишком подходит к теме собственных и нарицательных имен. Как вы определяете приложение в этом случае, то есть почему "Уют" - это приложение? Может быть, лучше не пользоваться этим термином вовсе, а не говорить про приложение?

Comment: Как определяю? Очень просто. С другими словами в этом предложении образует словосочетание именно слово _**журнал**_, являясь в предложении _дополнением_, а слово _**"Уют"**_  образует словосочетание **только** со словом _журнал_ и  является несогласованным _определением_ к этому _дополнению_. См.: _в номере (чего?) **журнала**; журнала (какого?) **"Уют"**_.

Comment: Приложение - это определение, выраженное именем существительным, согласующимся с определяемым словом в падеже.  В нашем случае нет согласования, но Вы называете "Уют" то приложением, то несогласованным определением. Так что это?

Comment: Допустим, что с названием журнала всё несложно, а как быть с выражением "сестра Маша"? Здесь всегда ж. род, по грамматическим связям трудно определить приложение и определяемое слово. А если еще появится врач Петрова, то совсем всё непросто: согласование со сказуемым имеет варианты, получается, что приложение тоже меняет свой статус? Как бы со всем этим "просто" разобраться?

Comment: _Vera: Приложение - это определение, выраженное именем существительным, согласующимся с определяемым словом в падеже._ === . Не только это. Из Розенталя: Приложение несогласованное. Приложение, которое не согласуется с определяемым словом в падеже и сохраняет неизменную начальную форму независимо от падежной формы определяемого слова.
Сюда относятся:
а) некоторые прозвища…
б) условные названия литературных произведений, органов печати, предприятий, гостиниц, пароходов и т. д...

Comment: _Vera: Допустим, что с названием журнала всё несложно…_ === Несложно. Тем не менее… (см. первую редакцию своего ответа).

Comment: _Vera: а как быть с выражением "сестра Маша"?_ === А это лучше в отдельной теме разобрать.

Comment: Замечательно,  но в академической грамматике указано, что приложение согласуется с определяемым словом в падеже. А если не согласуется, то ведет себя как сложное слово (горе-охотник).  Что остается от классической формулировки в сочетании нариц.-собств.? Приложение - это не определение, оно не всегда выражено существительным и оно  не всегда согласуется с определяемым словом. Почему бы тогда  не называть его хотя бы несогласованным определением и забыть о приложении?

Comment: _Vera: Почему бы тогда не называть его хотя бы несогласованным определением и забыть о приложении?_ === Я -- **за!**

Answer (score 2):

> Как должно правильно звучать предложение?
>
> В сентябрьском номере **журнала "Уюта"** можно прочитать...

**Правильно:**

*В сентябрьском номере **журнала "Уют"** можно прочитать...*

(перед словом *"Уют"* стоит родовое слово -- ***журнал***).

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ:**

Если при названии есть **родовое слово**, название не склоняется; при отсутствии родового слова название бы склонялось.

**Примеры** (с другим названием журнала, поскольку название "Уют" без родового слова почему-то не смотрится):

*В последнем номере **"Огонька"**  был помещен фотоочерк...*

*В последнем номере журнала **"Огонёк"**  был помещен фотоочерк...*